# How to find existing files in other OS through Ubuntu in a dual-boot system?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, windows, files

I installed Ubuntu alongside of Windows Vista to try it out. I can't get the wireless to work. Firmware missing error.

Secondly, how do I find my files that exists in Vista through Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please ask only one question per question, also have a look in the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking two completely independent questions here.

---

About the 'Firmware missing error.':

- Get your pc connected to the internet using a wired connection, then
- enable `universe` and `multiverse` repositories in 'Software Sources', then
- install `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages and finally
- reboot.

That will probably provide the kernel module the firmware it is looking for.

---

About accessing files on a Windows (NTFS) partition, see the Ubuntu Community Wiki article [MountingWindowsPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions). That will work if you installed Ubuntu on a separate partition. In case you're in a Wubi installation, just navigate to the /host directory.

Comment: If you used Wubi, just navigate to File System and then to `host`.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS It's already there, right? "In case you're in a Wubi installation, just navigate to the /host directory." as added by EmersonHsieh.

Comment: My mistake. [filler]

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same as you. What I did is connect the laptop to an Ethernet cable and then go to drivers and update. This should resolve that problem. As for the other one I'm not actually sure you can do that since it's partitioned. Maybe just use a usb stick drive and transfer the files.

Comment: The latter is possible. In fact, Ubuntu supports quite a few filesystems: FAT, NTFS, EXT2/3/4, ReiserFS, BtrFS, and many others, often without having to install new software,

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the computer via ethernet  as user86977 said, and then search for a program called **Additional Drivers**. Then, open  and **activate** the driver you need.

As for the second part, open the File Manager by opening **Home Folder** on the launcher dock to the left, then at the left side of the window, there will be a drive icon that says something like **[###]GB File System** or the name of the drive. If it is Vista, it will contain some folders:

- Program Files
- Users
- WINDOWS

as well as some more. Your files will be found somewhere in Users>[your user name]>My Documents or something else nearby. You can then drag and drop to your **Home folder**.

Bold text refers to names of programs or other text you should look for.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: open the *Dash* and search for **Additional Drivers**. In that window, you can search for your wireless driver.

For the second one, you can mount the Vista's NTFS partition as other users said above, or you can create a **new FAT32 partition** using *GParted* or, if you have, any partitioning tool for Windows. Then, you could put whatever you want on that partition, and access it from Windows or Linux.

The FAT32 partition method is what I use, I preffer it because then I have all my files more organized.

I hope you can solve it soon and tell us!

Comment: This answer isn't fundamentally different from the others; perhaps you want to make a comment? I think the FAT32 pat is a good idea.